# PHP Highlight phrases in a string

Tags: php, regex

I'm having a text where I want to highlight certain phrases in this text. Highlighting is done by making the phrase bold `<b>phrase</b>`.

So I created an array with phrases that must be highlighted. See below:

```
$phrases = ['iphone 7 plus', 'iphone 7'];
```

I created a function which will highlight the phrases for me.

```
function highlight_phrases($string, $phrases, $tag = 'strong')
{
    foreach($phrases as $phrase) {
        $string = preg_replace('/' . $phrase . '/i', '<' . $tag . '>$0</' . $tag . '>', $string);
    }    
    return $string;
}
```

Now when I have the following text:

```
This is some text about the iPhone 7 and this i really a nice peace of engineering.
```

This will turn into:

```
This is some text about the <strong>iPhone 7</strong> and this i really a nice peace of engineering.
```

OK, all fine!

Now I have a different text:

```
We are now talking about the iPhone 7 Plus, which is very big!
```

**And here is what is going wrong**, it turns this into:

```
We are now talking about the <strong><strong>iPhone 7</strong> Plus</strong>, which is very big!
```

When this html is printed on the screen, it just looks fine. But the code itself is wrong because of the `strong` tag inside the `strong` tag.

How will I be able to fix this?

**NOTE:** The `$phrases` array might become very large, maybe every phone you know might be in it as a phrase

Comment: Is this the only purpose of your PHP class? If yes, you can come up with a client-side solution, only using javascript.

Comment: You need to use a regex like `/iphone 7 plus|iphone 7/i` replacing your `for` loop. Just run something like `return preg_replace('/' . implode("|", $phrases) . '/i', '<' . $tag . '>$0</' . $tag . '>', $string);` (also, a good idea is to `preg_quote` those phrases, and make sure the longest come first).

Comment: @treecon, I've also thought about using javascript because it's only for readability and making the difference between `iphone 7` and `iphone 7 plus` more clear.

Comment: Don't use `preg_replace` inside a foreach loop. Let's `preg_replace` do it all alone.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, you should turn that into an answer!

Comment: @Timo002: Good, I posted a sample demo with explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build an alternation-based regex dynamically while also `preg_quote`ing the items (to automatically escape all special regex metacharacters) and order them by length in a descending order (else, the shorter substrings will prevent longer ones from matching, the same way you had in the original code). The expression for the 2 search phrases in question will look like `/iphone 7 plus|iphone 7/i`. This should replace your `for` loop that could match the same term several times.

Here is a [sample PHP demo](http://ideone.com/bXGHkl):

```
function highlight_phrases($string, $phrases, $tag = 'strong')
{
    usort($phrases, function($a,$b){
        return strlen($b)-strlen($a);
    });
    //print_r($phrases); // => Array ( [0] => iphone 7 plus [1] => iphone 7 )
    $pattern = '/' . implode("|", array_map(function ($x) { 
        return preg_quote($x, '/'); 
    }, $phrases)) . '/i';
    // echo "$pattern"; // =>  /iphone 7 plus|iphone 7/i
    return preg_replace($pattern, '<' . $tag . '>$0</' . $tag . '>', $string);
}

$phrases = ['iphone 7', 'iphone 7 plus'];
$s = "This is some text about the iPhone 7 and this i really a nice peace of engineering. We are now talking about the iPhone 7 Plus, which is very big!";
echo highlight_phrases($s, $phrases);
// => This is some text about the <strong>iPhone 7</strong> and this i really a nice peace of engineering. We are now talking about the <strong>iPhone 7 Plus</strong>, which is very big!
```

A couple of words about the pattern: in an NFA regex, the unanchored alternation groups match the first alternative branch that finds a match, unlike in POSIX, where the longest match is looked for. That is why the longer search phrase must appear before the shorter ones. See [*Remember That The Regex Engine Is Eager*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html).

Answer (score 0):

your function now uses preg_replace() as powerless als str_replace()

Use the power of the regular expression:

`$phrases = ['iphone 7(?: plus)?'];`

This would search for "iphone 7" optionally followed by " plus"
The last question mark makes the part between ( ) optional.

(and the ?: makes it not appear as a $2 in the second part of the replace function.
)

Comment: I think the `$phrases` array might become to difficult with this approach. Someone with no regex knowledge must be able to maintain the array.